# php artisan route:list ReflectionException class does not exist but its there?

Tags: laravel-5

Im having this problem when i use the command said in the title, its not finding my LoginController that i have in my auth folder.
It seams that it wants to load the controller using the wrong path.

Its weird because i never touched or moved anything from that controller i was creating a migration when i notice the error trying the route:list command as for my application it works normally except when i logout it doesn't redirect to my login view anymore it no redirects to public thus showing a 404.

I don't know what i did that it broke those things.

I tried changing the namespace of my controller to the one it shows on the error but its weird because when i change it the new error shows the correct path for the controller but since i changed it does not finds it again.
Also i tried the commands: config:cache, composer dump-autoload, composer update.

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

}
```

My web routes:

```
<?php

Auth::routes();


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');



Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth',  'auth.admin'])->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('/ImagenAudioVideo',  'PlantillaController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::resource('/Imagen',  'PlantillaImagenesController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::resource('/Audio',  'PlantillaAudiosController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::resource('/Video',  'PlantillaVideosController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::resource('/ImagenAudio',  'PlantillaImagenesAudioController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::resource('/EditarUsuario',  'EditarUsuariosController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);

    Auth::routes(['register' => false]);

    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

});
```

The exception:

```
  ReflectionException  : Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\LoginController does not exist

  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ConfiguradorIEM/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790
```

notice how it shows a different path but when i change the namespace to the path shown in the exception it throws a new error with the previous  path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `Auth::routes();` declarations, the second one has the namespace `Admin`.

This is why you get this error: you have to remove the line `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);` inside the `Admin` namespaced `Route` because you are adding the `Admin` namespace to all the `Auth` controllers.

Remember that `Auth::routes();` are for the most **named** routes and the second route declaration override the first one.

Comment: You're welcome, please consider also upvoting the answer if it helps.

Comment: I tried up-voting but i need more reputation but i accepted the answer

Comment: I upvoted for you @dparoli :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still searching for a solution for such an error.

In my case, the error showed up only because I forgot to specify the namespace for my controller which was in the Billing directory.

And as soon as I added this line at the top of my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Billing;
```

The issue was resolved.